# Django "changes not reflected in a migration" with ImageField and custom storage

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-storage

My Django 1.8 app uses a third-party app ([django-avatar](https://github.com/grantmcconnaughey/django-avatar)) whose model contains an ImageField. I'm also using a custom DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE (S3BotoStorage from [django-storages-redux](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages)) in my project's settings.py. As a result, every time I run `manage.py migrate`, I get this warning about the avatar app:

> Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
>   Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.

... because [avatar's initial migration](https://github.com/grantmcconnaughey/django-avatar/blob/2.1.1/avatar/migrations/0001_initial.py#L23) references Django's default FileSystemStorage. Running makemigrations creates a new 0002 migration in the avatar app, to make its ImageField's storage match my project setting:

```
...
migrations.AlterField(
    model_name='avatar',
    name='avatar',
    field=models.ImageField(storage=storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage(), max_length=1024, upload_to=avatar.models.avatar_file_path, blank=True),
),
```

The problem is, this new migration is created in avatar installed in python's site-packages, outside my project (so outside git control, unavailable for deployment, etc.).

**What's the right way to handle migrations for a third-party app that uses an ImageField** (or FileField) in a project with custom DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE? I've considered:

- Just ignore the warning. The migration to change storage doesn't actually
  affect the DB schema, and since my project's DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE has been
  S3BotoStorage since the start, no data migration is needed.
- Use [settings.MIGRATION_MODULES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#migration-modules) to move avatar's
  migrations into my project. (And then carefully port over every future
  avatar migration to my copy--which seems error-prone.) 
  [EDIT: [this comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/0JrYUVhuvhw/cekgOp-TwyMJ) on the 
  django-users mailing list suggests this is the wrong approach.]
- Ask the django-avatar (or django-storages-redux) maintainers to change... what?
  (BTW, S3BotoStorage is already [deconstructible](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/1.3/storages/backends/s3boto.py#L65) -- that's not the problem.)
- Or...?

Comment: Hey medmunds, I'm the current maintainer of django-avatar and I would also like to know the answer to this. Do you think creating a another migration that changes the `ImageField.storage` attribute to reference `settings.AVATAR_STORAGE` would prevent this?

Comment: Hey Grant, thanks for the package! So, you'd add a schema migration to django-avatar and manually edit it to have something like `storage=get_storage_class(settings.AVATAR_STORAGE)()`? I think that might solve my problem, but you'd have to remember to edit every future django-avatar schemamigration the same way. Also, it *might* cause problems for people truly trying to migrate from one storage to another, because it wouldn't be freezing the state at the time of the migration (maybe -- not sure about this).

Comment: There's some discussion of migrations and storages in the Django tracker ([22373](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22373) and [22337](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22337)), but none of it in the context of third-party apps. I wonder if it would help to raise the issue over there?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm talking about. I think you're right about the issue of it not freezing the state of the migration. Even if I change it to use `AVATAR_STORAGE` that still won't fix the issue of changing `AVATAR_STORAGE` during a project's life. I'm really not sure how to go about this. I'll look into raising an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is... Ask the django-avatar maintainers to fix it.

If you want to simply use the default storage you should pass `None` or `django.core.files.storage.default_storage` to `ImageField`. In this case `storage` kwarg will not be passed to the field in the migration.

I created [PR](https://github.com/grantmcconnaughey/django-avatar/pull/130) to fix this.

Comment: Nice: `default_storage` -- didn't know about that. Won't django-avatar now also need a new migration to override the explicit reference to `django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage()` in its [initial migration](https://github.com/grantmcconnaughey/django-avatar/blob/2.1.1/avatar/migrations/0001_initial.py#L23)?

Comment: @medmunds
I just modified existing migration in PR, however I'm not sure if this is correct approach/